# vb.net Crystal Reports - Parameters

Tags: vb.net, winforms, parameters, crystal-reports

just a quick one this...

Is it possible to programatically get a list of parameters from a crystal report class?

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `rpt` is a `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument`:

```
Dim param As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldDefinition
For Each param In rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    'You can get the name with this
    'param.Name

    'You can set the value like this
    rpt.SetParameterValue(param.Name, "Your Value")
Next
```